# Run a non-console graphic session without a RDP session on Windows

Tags: rdp

How can I run a non-console graphic session without [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) session on windows? For example, if I want to create my own [remote desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) server with another protocol?

Comment: I'm trying to transfer your desktop as a video stream. I want clients to connect to the server to different accounts. But the client does not need to know about the PRD. The problem is that the graphical shell windows not displayed if there is no active connection. Now it happened, but if you open RDP session from the same computer. But it looks stupid.

Comment: The client application handles the keystrokes and sends them to a server application that handles them. And I need a minimum delay of the video streaming.

Comment: Yes, but why **video**. From you have described I have yet to see a reason you can't just embed the [mstsc ActiveX control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh339677%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your client application and just use that.

Comment: I can not give the user access to the server via RDP

Comment: Then you will need to write your own RDP Provider as per my answer, you may want to look in to some kind of hardware acceleration for encoding the video if you want to be able to let more than 1 or 2 people on. (BTW, you are still letting people connect Via RDP its just via a custom protocol), Please edit your original question about what the goals of your project, I feel that there is a must better solution available but without more details of what you are capturing, and what your constrains are, we can't help you.

Comment: Client and server communicate via TCP. Server captures images from the screen directshow filters, then programmatically encoded video stream and sent to the client. The problem occurred in two connections. It turned out only with the opening of the RDP connection

Comment: This is what is called a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) "That is, you are trying to solve problem `X`, and you think solution `Y` would work, but instead of asking about `X` when you run into trouble, you ask about `Y`". I suggest you open a new question and ask your `X` of streaming direct show filters from more than one user session.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the term to do what you are looking for is [Remote Desktop Protocol Provider Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd919947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That MSDN link will walk you through the process of writing your own provider.

It will be a lot of work, but if you want to make your own provider it can be done. If you explain more about ***why*** you want to do this we may be able to provide better solutions.